# Set up Express/EJS server

Tags: express, ejs

I have a function which contains an array of objects, and want to bring them in to be used with the .esj/.htlm pages (though data variable I assume). Here is what I have, not sure how to go about this, thanks!

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
// want to get the data in here
res.render('index', data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't learn the basics.
You can do this by:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
       // call your function here
       //normal sync function
       data=function_name()
       res.render('index', data);

       //if you are using promisified function
       function_name()
       .then(data => {
            res.render('index', data);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            res.send(error)
        })
    })
```